# Eclipse Scout : hook on event of opening fields tooltip

Tags: tooltip, action, eclipse-scout

I would like to know if I can hook on event on opening tooltip on fields, or clicking on `i` icon on field right.

[image]

What I would like to do is, if user has special permissions, open new pop up form if user click on this icon.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no event reflected to the Scout Model (java code) when the user clicks on the tooltip.

What you can do:

1/ Set a diffent Tooltip information for a given user.

2/ Add a menu on the field (that is only visible/enabeled for certain users). This is the way we add additional actions at field level.

[image: Eclipse Scout Screenshot with a Menu on a field]

3/ (currently only for `StringField`) If you only have one action you could set the property `hasAction` to `true` instead of using a menu. This will bring up a clickable arrow inside the field, just implement `execAction`. The idea behind this arrow button is to follow a link or open the email client, but you can use it for any other action as well.

[image: Eclipse Scout StringField with with hasAction==true]

Comment: This is a great solution, and I like it. But if I add menu on field, and set visible = false and enabled = false and set tooltip, tooltip icon is visible but not clickable. Is this a bug?

Comment: Moving your question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571754/eclipse-scout-neon-menu-and-tooltip-on-a-field

Comment: This issue was fixed in M5 version of scout

Comment: I have added a third possibility for StringField