# Eclipse Scout Neon: Menu and Tooltip on a field

Tags: eclipse-scout

This is a screenshot if you put a Menu on a `StringField`:

[image: Eclipse Scout Screenshot with a Menu on a field]

This is a screenshot if you put a Tooltip on a `StringField`:

[image: Eclipse Scout Screenshot with a Tooltip on a field]

This is a screenshot if you put a Menu and a Tooltip on a `StringField`:

[image: Eclipse Scout Screenshot with a Menu and Tooltip on a field]

- the `(i)` icon from the tooltip is the button to open the menu list.
- the tooltip text is not visible.

Did I miss something?

Is this a known issue?

Comment: This issue was fixed in M5 version of scout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue. If a tooltip and a menu are provided, a combined popup should be shown including the tooltip text and the menu items. But this has not been implemented yet. Feel free to open a bug.

However, if you only have one action you could set the property `hasAction` to `true` instead of using a menu. This will bring up a clickable arrow inside the field, actually intended to follow a link or open the email client. But you could also use it for any other action as well, just implement `execAction`. Please note that this feature is only available for string fields so far.

StringField with `hasAction=true`:

[image: Eclipse Scout StringField with with hasAction==true]